# AVPlayer, Play a local file URL that is currently being written to?

Tags: swift, video, stream, avplayer, mp4

I have been trying to use a custom `AVPlayerItem` that lets me copy the currently playing media to file after it has been downloaded while it is streaming into the `AVPlayer`, essentially letting me cache the displayed video while showing the video as soon as possible.

Unfortunately, my application sometimes needs to download mp4 files from a server (that I don't control) that is giving the mime type as image/gif although the downloaded file IS an mp4 file. Because of this, my `AVPlayer` is not "streaming" in the video as it's downloaded, and only shows it once the file is completely downloaded and it realizes the file really is an MP4.

My thought is now to just download the file directly to a local file with a .mp4 extension that a standard `AVPlayerItem` can stream in, and write to this file while reading from it with the `AVPlayerItem`. Is this possible? Will the AVPlayerItem pause when it is still downloading/buffering the incomplete data or will it just produce an error without displaying anything? Is there a better way I can be doing this?